# Pandas interpolating missing entries in time series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

Attached is kind of time series I am dealing with. If we see df, timestamp is different for each name. Also, there are missing time stamp and values at places.
I am trying to get a time series where the series is mapped from min element of time series to max element of time series. Also, missing value if interpolated/extrapolated.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO('''\
Values
1992-08-27 07:30:00,28.0,27.0  
1992-08-27 08:00:00,28.2,27.0    
1992-08-27 09:00:00,28.8,27.5  
1992-08-27 09:30:00,29.0  
1992-08-27 10:30:00,29.6,26.0  
1992-08-27 11:00:00,29.8,27.0  
1992-08-27 11:30:00,30.0,27.0
''')
s = pd.read_csv(data, squeeze=True)
s = pd.DataFrame(s)
s = s.reset_index()
s.columns = ['datetime', 'value1', 'value2']
s['name'] = 'A'

df =s.copy()


data = io.StringIO('''\
Values
1992-08-27 08:00:00,29.2,29.0     
1992-08-27 09:30:00,30.0,37.0  
1992-08-27 10:30:00,24.6,37.0  
1992-08-27 11:00:00,24.8,37.0  
''')
s = pd.read_csv(data, squeeze=True)
s = pd.DataFrame(s)
s = s.reset_index()
s.columns = ['datetime', 'value1', 'value2']
s['name'] = 'B'

df = df.append(s, sort=False)
```

Trying/Failing:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
df.resample('M').interpolate()
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Expected df: Possible to get here?

```
   datetime  value1  value2 name
1992-08-27 07:30:00    28.0    27.0    A
1992-08-27 08:00:00    28.2    27.0    A
1992-08-27 08:30:00    28.5    27.25    A
1992-08-27 09:00:00    28.8    27.5    A
1992-08-27 09:30:00    29.0    27.0    A
1992-08-27 10:00:00    29.6    26.5    A
1992-08-27 10:30:00    29.6    27.0    A
1992-08-27 11:00:00    29.8    27.0    A
1992-08-27 11:30:00    30.0    27.0    A
1992-08-27 07:30:00    29.2    29.0    B
1992-08-27 08:00:00    29.2    29.0    B
1992-08-27 08:30:00    29.2    29.0    B
1992-08-27 09:00:00    29.2    29.0    B
1992-08-27 09:30:00    30.0    37.0    B
1992-08-27 10:30:00    24.6    37.0    B
1992-08-27 11:00:00    24.8    37.0    B
1992-08-27 11:30:00    24.8    37.0    B
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is indeed that you are dealing with duplicate indices: for instance both the A and B dataframes share index 1992-08-27 08:00:00.

In order to fix this problem, I would suggest grouping by name prior to applying your resampling and interpolation.

You could try something like:

`df.groupby('name').resample('30T').asfreq().interpolate(method='linear', limit_area="inside")`

**EDIT:** Because of multi-indexing, the above line will only allow you to use  the linear interpolation method. In order to unlock other methods, you will need to drop the second index by name (created by groupby).

For instance `df2=df.groupby('name').resample('30T').asfreq().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).interpolate(method='values')` returns the following dataframe:

```
value1  value2 name datetime                                
1992-08-27 07:30:00    28.0   27.00    A
1992-08-27 08:00:00    28.2   27.00    A
1992-08-27 08:30:00    28.5   27.25  NaN
1992-08-27 09:00:00    28.8   27.50    A
1992-08-27 09:30:00    29.0   27.00    A
1992-08-27 10:00:00    29.3   26.50  NaN
1992-08-27 10:30:00    29.6   26.00    A
1992-08-27 11:00:00    29.8   27.00    A
1992-08-27 11:30:00    30.0   27.00    A
1992-08-27 08:00:00    29.2   29.00    B
1992-08-27 08:30:00    28.5   27.25  NaN
1992-08-27 09:00:00    28.8   27.50  NaN
1992-08-27 09:30:00    30.0   37.00    B
1992-08-27 10:00:00    29.3   26.50  NaN
1992-08-27 10:30:00    24.6   37.00    B
1992-08-27 11:00:00    24.8   37.00    B
```